# Attempted import error: 'Toast' is not exported from 'react-bootstrap'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

```
import React from 'react';
import { Toast } from 'react-bootstrap';

export function Confirmation({ toggle }) {
        return (
            <Toast onClose={() => toggle(false)}>
                <Toast.Header>
                        <strong className="mr-auto">Your Order Is In The Oven!</strong>
                        <small>just now</small>
            </Toast.Header>
            <Toast.Body>
                Your delicious pizza will be with you in 30 minutes!
            </Toast.Body>
            </Toast>
        );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please read the documentation first before post any questions. Visit https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/toasts/

change

> import { Toast } from 'react-bootstrap';

with

> import Toast from 'react-bootstrap/Toast'

Comment: did you installed `react-bootstrap`? if yes, that's solution works 100%

Answer (score 0):

Change your import to
 import { Toast } from 'react-bootstrap/Toast'

Comment: Toast have `export default` so, you cant export it with destruction method. Thanks